# Access to NTP via IP which doesn't change often

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, ntp

I'm trying to sync the clock of our production server located in a data center with pool.ntp.org. For security reason, our servers has no internet access unless we requested to open specific ip/port explicitly. I worked out a list of IPs based on

```
0.asia.ntp.org
1.asia.ntp.org
2.asia.ntp.org
3.asia.ntp.org
```

Not realizing ntp.org is using round robin DNS and the servers being voluntary, they changes from time to time. In fact the IP I've got from `3.asia.ntp.org` last month is no longer working now.

I'm wondering if there's a publicly known NTP server that doesn't change as often or if there's a way to go around this without having to request an update to the firewall on a monthly basis. I believe many admin is facing the same issue here.

Comment: Call your ISP.  They probably have a local NTP server on a fixed IP that you can use, and they will have the smallest latency/jitter.  Many ISPs have a NTP server, they just don't advertise it very much.

Comment: Or you can setup one or two NTP servers of your own (perhaps in a DMZ), have those synchronize with pool.ntp.org, and point your production server to your owhn NTP server(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ntp.org provides a list of [primary](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/StratumOneTimeServers) and [secondary](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/StratumTwoTimeServers) time servers. I think it's reasonable to assume these will generally be static addresses, especially compared to the NTP pool which intentionally rotates every hour.

Please note that not all are open/public access and abide by the [rules of engagement](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/RulesOfEngagement), which suggest using secondary servers over primary among other things.

Comment: I once ran a script that did lookups on some of those pool addresses and collected the IP addresses every hour. After a couple weeks I had collected over 200 addresses. This is not a practical resource in limited IP access situation. The ISP time servers should be used. Any decent colo provider has a couple of them.

Comment: Thanks, I found that some of the servers has Use DNS = No, which means IP would most like be static.

Comment: Old post but for the future Google hit: 1) NEVER hardcode NTP addresses, for any reason. NEVER.  2) Run a NTP server on another host then.  Nobody will argue with you because this is a requirement imposed by the server's constraint. 3) In general if you have to do something unorthodox (hackish) and you don't control it, you must write a monitoring application so when it eventually fails people will immediately know why instead of troubleshooting alll the side effects.

Comment: Admins of NTP who are hard-coded by inconsiderate clients get annoyed, They may do things to discourage you, like randomly sending wildly-incorrect dates just to your IP. (How would your system behave if told it is Dec 31 1999?). Don't.Hardcode.NTP.

Comment: More NTP client recommendations at https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18753835

Answer (score 1):

As an NTP Pool Server Operator, I'd kindly ask that if you can't allow NTP out to any IP address from you servers, then please set up an NTP server of your own, have that sync to the pool, and all your servers sync to that. That way you're still using the pool as designed, your servers all get their NTP service, and no singular NTP Pool server operator is getting all your traffic for eternity.